# ¿Cómo elegir una fila y columna de una listbox en VisualBasic?

Tags: vb.net, mysql-workbench, listbox

Necesito elegir una fila y columna en especifico de una tabla SQL a través de una listbox.
He visto algunos métodos pero ninguno me sirve actualmente y me hace mucha falta
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(ListBox.Items(0), DataRowView)
Dim value As String = drv("Txt_Campo").ToString

Comment: Éste código selecciona una columna específica de la primera fila de un ListBox